The FastAPI application gets stuck when try to capture request.body() in a middleware when called internally
class RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    async def dispatch(self, request: Request, call_next):
        tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)
        # breakpoint()

        # Extract trace context from incoming request headers
        context = extract(request.headers)

        # Start a new span with the extracted context
        with tracer.start_as_current_span(f"HTTP {request.method} {request.url.path}", context=context) as span:
            start_time = time.time()

            # Extract request information
            user_id = request.headers.get("X-USER-ID", "")
            session_id = request.headers.get("X-SESSION-ID", "")
            request_id = request.headers.get("X-REQUEST-ID", "")

            request_body = await request.body()
            # request_body = await request.body()

            try:
                request_body = request_body.decode('utf-8')
            except Exception:
                request_body = str(request_body)

            # Inject trace context into outgoing request headers
            new_header = MutableHeaders(request._headers)
            inject(new_header)
            request._headers = new_header
            request.scope.update(headers=request.headers.raw)

            # Call the next middleware or endpoint
            response = await call_next(request)


            # Capture response body
            response_body = b""
            async for chunk in response.body_iterator:
                response_body += chunk

            # Create a new response object with the same content
            new_response = StreamingResponse(BytesIO(response_body), status_code=response.status_code,
                                             headers=dict(response.headers))

            try:
                response_body = response_body.decode('utf-8')
            except Exception:
                response_body = str(response_body)

            # Prepare log entry

            span_context = span.get_span_context()
            trace_id = format(span_context.trace_id, '032x')  # Convert trace_id to hex string
            span_id = format(span_context.span_id, '016x')  # Convert span_id to hex string

            parent_span_id = None
            if span.parent:
                parent_span_context = span.parent.span_context
                parent_span_id = format(parent_span_context.span_id, '016x')

            # Prepare log entry
            log_entry = {
                "timestamp": int(start_time * 1000),  # Convert to milliseconds
                "user_id": user_id,
                "session_id": session_id,
                "request_id": request_id,
                "trace_id": trace_id,
                "span_id": span_id,
                "parent_span_id":parent_span_id,
                "url": str(request.url),
                "url_params": dict(request.query_params),
                "request_body": request_body,
                "response_body": response_body,
                "response_status": response.status_code
            }

            # Log the request and response details
            logging.info(log_entry)
            # print(log_entry)

            return new_response

This is the middleware I am using, I am getting request.body() in first service. Then when this service calls another service which also uses same code of middleware, then this request.body() gets stuck with no error.
I tried some solutions which use set_body() and get_body() but didn't worked out for me.
This->.
I expect that I can capture request.body() in each service.

The problem here is that after you read request body stream, it's empty and can't be read again. So, you need to create new stream (generator), that will get data from body_data you already have and return it.

Does this answer your question?
